# Case Statement in Where Clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, data-partitioning

Good day!

I have a query using SQL which gives a result set of sales per tenant. Now, I want to get a final result set that shows the top 5 and bottom 5 in terms of sales (may be flexible, but sets 5 as an example)

I used rank function to get the ranking per sales, and was able to get almost the desired output by displaying the top and bottom tenant based on sales.

**Here's the part of the code from stored procedure**

```
@RankedBy int = 5

SELECT *FROM (
            SELECT #TEMPTABLE5.*, 'BOTTOM' AS 'RankName' ,
                   Rank() over (Partition BY Business ORDER BY Sales ) AS Rank
                   FROM #TEMPTABLE5
            ) rs WHERE Rank <= @RankedBy 

UNION ALL

SELECT *FROM (
            SELECT #TEMPTABLE5.*, 'BOTTOM' AS 'RankName' ,
                   Rank() over (Partition BY Business ORDER BY Sales DESC ) AS Rank
                   FROM #TEMPTABLE5
            ) rs WHERE Rank <= @RankedBy 

order by  Business, RankName DESC ,Rank
```

**and this is the result set**

```
tenant      business    sales   rankName    rank
sample A1   food        1500    top            1
sample A2   food        1400    top            2
sample A3   food        1300    top            3
sample A4   food        1200    top            4
sample A5   food        1100    top            5
sample A6   food         100    bottom         1
sample A7   food         200    bottom         2
sample A8   food         300    bottom         3
sample A9   food         400    bottom         4
sample A10  food         500    bottom         5
sample B1   non food    2000    top            1
sample B2   non food    1800    top            2
sample B3   non food    1500    top            3
sample B3   non food    1500    bottom         1
sample B2   non food    1800    bottom         2
sample B1   non food    2000    bottom         3
```

Based on the given information, I already achieved to get the top and bottom based on NUMBER ASSIGNED IN @RankedBy Parameter.

WHAT i want now, is to have a condition where, if the result set per business is **BELOW OR LESS THAN THE PARAMETER @RankedBy**, the result should no longer include the BOTTOM PART, like this sample CORRECT result:

```
tenant      business       sales    rankName     rank
    sample A1   food        1500    top            1
    sample A2   food        1400    top            2
    sample A3   food        1300    top            3
    sample A4   food        1200    top            4
    sample A5   food        1100    top            5
    sample A6   food         100    bottom         1
    sample A7   food         200    bottom         2
    sample A8   food         300    bottom         3
    sample A9   food         400    bottom         4
    sample A10  food         500    bottom         5
    sample B1   non food    2000    top            1
    sample B2   non food    1800    top            2
    sample B3   non food    1500    top            3
```

*non food has 3 records only, less than the parameter assigned in @RankedBy which is 5.*

On my existing code, what I planned is to have a count per business and put the condition in where clause, but I found it inefficient and ineffective.

If anyone among you experts could give a more efficient coding or could correct my initial codes.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0):

I would create a temporary table with the result of the full query, then do two simple queries with `ORDER BY sales LIMIT 5` and `ORDER BY sales DESC LIMIT 5`.

The benefit is that you can do other refinements on the temporary table if you need, like computing the mean, average,...

Comment: Let's see whether I can get the syntax right the first time: `CREATE TEMP TABLE foo (tenant TEXT, business TEXT,sales INTEGER, rankName TEXT, rank INTEGER);  INSERT INTO foo SELECT ...as you did; SELECT * from foo order by sales limit 5;`

Comment: LIMIT is mysql I beleive. For SQL Server `SELECT TOP 5` etc

Comment: Sorry, I missed that it was for sql-server... "SELECT TOP" seems like a good candidate though, still on the temporary table. The temporary table will simplify your query, you can avoid the UNION by simply doing two inserts for instance.

Comment: I need to add a column where it will state if it is TOP or BOTTOM, that's I way I made it that way..

Answer (score 0):

you add having at the bottom part like this

```
  @RankedBy int = 5

    SELECT *FROM (
        SELECT #TEMPTABLE5.*, 'TOP' AS 'RankName' ,
               Rank() over (Partition BY Business ORDER BY Sales ) AS Rank
               FROM #TEMPTABLE5
        ) rs WHERE Rank <= @RankedBy 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT tenant,business,sales,rankName,rank FROM (
       select tenant,business,sales,rankName,rank,max(rank) from(
        SELECT #TEMPTABLE5.*, 'BOTTOM' AS 'RankName' ,
               Rank() over (Partition BY Business ORDER BY Sales DESC ) AS Rank
               FROM #TEMPTABLE5
        ) rs WHERE Rank <= @RankedBy)rk 
   group by tenant,business,sales,rankName,rank Having MAX(Rank) = @RankedBy

 order by  Business, RankName DESC ,Rank
```